# How to replace occurance of numbers with single value?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have below code

```java
String str = "/admin/3138/misc";
boolean isNumbers = str.chars().anyMatch(Character::isDigit);
System.out.println(isNumbers);
if (isNumbers) {
    str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "%d");
    System.out.println("->" + str);
}
```

Which gives output:

```
admin/%d%d%d%d/misc
```

I need:

```
admin/%d/misc
```

So from string if numbers found just replace with `%d` one only, not every digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your regex to `"[0-9]+"`

```java
if (isNumbers) {
    str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+", "%d");
    System.out.println("->" + str);
}
```

Oracle's doc: [Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by m.antkowitz is correct; however, be careful of the risks of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). If someone names a directory "/abc/%def/123", and you then translate that into "/abc/%def/%d" and try to use that in a String.format() call, your application will break. To get around this, guard against the occurrence of "%d" in the name:

```
str = str.replace("%", "%%").replaceAll("[0-9]+", "%d");
```

This replaces a `%` with `%%` which, when printed using `printf()` or `String.format()`, causes a literal "%" to be output.